# How to move app icons using script/commands on android?

Tags: android, adb, root

I want to be able to move app icons to specific positions on android 9. The reason for this is because I was running low on storage (my phone has only 16GB of storage), and I formatted part of the microSD card as internal storage. This did help but also introduced a new problem - since the SD card is loaded a few seconds after the original internal storage, each reboot completely messes up all icons, sending them to new pages as if they are freshly installed apps. And each time I have to spend 5 minutes fixing them. It would be nice to have a script that would automatically set them to specific positions.

I really have no idea how to do it nor I was able to find any soultion on the web. My phone is rooted and I can connect it to pc and send adb commands, so maybe it's possible?

Comment: The launche which organizes your app icons is just an app. Therefore there is no general answer to your question. The easiest way would to solve your problems would be switching to a launcher that allows to save/backup and restore to a file so you would be able to restore it when it breaks again. Anyway your question is not really on-topic here, https://android.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask. In that case also include the Android OS version, the phone model name and the app package name of the used launcher.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient), however that you could does not mean you should though

[image]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

helper = ViewClient.view_client_helper()
oid = helper.ui_device.find_object(ui_selector="desc@YouTube").oid
t, l, r, b = helper.ui_object.get_bounds(oid=oid)
s_x = int(l + (r - l)/2)
s_y = int(t + (b - t)/2)
e_x = 300
e_y = 700
helper.ui_device.drag(s_x, s_y, e_x, e_y, 50)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. So, as far as I understand, I have to download the AndroidViewClient library on my phone using ADB or Termux, and then run this code, replacing:
e_x = 300, 
e_y = 700: 
with the desired position of the apps and replacing desc@YouTube with the name of the app I want to move. My questions are: how do I check the coordinates of the desired place on the wallpaper, and does it work if the app is on another tab? This will most likely be quite tedious, but I can probably do this for every app and then combine it into a .sh file.

Comment: You can get the coordinates with a screenshot, however I don't think you will be able to do all you want from the phone itself.